# Symfony Doctrine so many request

Tags: php, performance, symfony, doctrine

In my API Symfony I have so many request generated by doctrine and I don't understand why.

[image: Architecture]

My Controller Method:

```
/**
     * @Route("/{id}/byteam", name="numero_numero")
     */
    public function index(Race $race): Response
    {
        $grille=[];
        $y=0;
        $ligne=0;
        $nbPilote = 600 + 20;
        for ($i=0;$i<$nbPilote;$i++){
            $grille[$ligne][$y]['num'] = $i+1;
            $grille[$ligne][$y]['pilote'] = null;

            $y++;
            if ($y>=4){
                $y=0;
                $ligne++;
            }
        }

        $listeTeam = [];
        $listeTeam = $this->teamRepository->findAllByRace($race);
        throw new \Exception('Stop');
        $elite = new Team();
        $elite->setName('Pilote Elite');
        $ordre = [];
        foreach ($this->inscriptionRepository->listeElite($race) as $inscription){
            $elite->addInscription($inscription);
            $ordre[] = $inscription->getId();
        }
        $elite->setOrdre($ordre);
        array_unshift($listeTeam , $elite);


        $sansTeam = new Team();
        $sansTeam->setName('Sans Team');
        $ordre = [];
        foreach ($this->inscriptionRepository->listeInscritSansTeam($race) as $inscription){
            $sansTeam->addInscription($inscription);
            $ordre[] = $inscription->getId();
        }
        $sansTeam->setOrdre($ordre);
        $listeTeam[] = $sansTeam;

        return $this->render('numero/byteam.html.twig', [
            'grille'=>$grille,
            'listeTeam'=> $listeTeam
        ]);
    }
```

My Repo Method:

```
public function findAllByRace(Race $race): ?array
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->select('t,i,u')
            ->join('t.inscriptions','i')
            ->join('i.user','u')
            ->andWhere("t.race = :race")
            ->setParameter('race', $race)
            ->orderBy('t.name','ASC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()
        ;
    }
```

With Repo Request (236 db calls):

[image]

Without Repo Request (23 db calls):

[image]

I have add `throw` for get Symfony debug bar.
I hope you understand me, my English is bad.

Comment: Click on queries in bar and take a look which queries are repeated.